# Cant see why I am getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, database

I have tried everything but i keep getting this error.

**Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host

Is it possible that my server is blocking it? How do i fix it

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database',$username,$password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and the dbinfo.php is:

```
$host="mysql.spri.co.za;port=3307"; $database="kruger_park_live"; $username="*****"; $password="*****";
```

Comment: Change `'` to `"` quotes in `$dbh` definition

Comment: You should learn the difference between single quote and double quote in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database",$username,$password);`

When you use single quotes variables are not being replaced with their values.

Comment: I have tried this, it is not working, maybe there is a connection problem

Comment: So can you connect to the server using some tool (like Mysql Workbench) with this credentials?

Comment: well it changed the error code: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server

Comment: yep I am logged into the server and I just pinged it to see what happens

Comment: @SeanKonig try error handling, like `try{}catch(){}` it will echo out, a precise error, as to why you are getting the error

Comment: @php NoOb sorry this is the first time i am really using php to do something like this and I dont know where to add what you are suggesting

Comment: @SeanKonig check this link. http://pastebin.com/mcb0vT5V and run your code, it will tell you where the problem is

Comment: Call to a member function setAttribute() on a non-object in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />

Comment: this my code: try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database',$username,$password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
    }
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {

Comment: @phpNoOb this whole thing is no totally confusing me

Comment: Remove the setAttribute for now, and try your query again.

Comment: now i get this: Data Loaded: ERROR:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '$host' (25)<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in <b>/home/sea503/public_html/phpsqlinfo_addrow.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br />